# Any way to debug Firebase cloud function runtime or syntax error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I often stumble upon:

> functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

The code is big error can be anywhere. Isn't there a reliable way to know which line it stumble upon that causes the error?

Since the function can't run I can't access logs. And Emulator also show same unhelpful message.
This is detrimental to the use of cloud functions due to huge time it takes to look for bug whithout anyclue where to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to debug, which I found a way almost by luck:

After following the installation "npm install -g firebase-tools" instructions from this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator?hl=en&authuser=0

From within function directory:

- Run: firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
- Click on the localhost link presented, this will open a browser window and enable debugging.
- From my IDE webstorm, all I had to do was click on the "Play" button to have the debug run through all the function code and spot all the syntax issues. Once fixed, I was able to place breakpoints in the code and have access to full debug features. It was impossible to work without this.